# Executing backup script on external HDD plug using udev

Tags: debian, udev

I have tried to write a custom udev rule to run a backup.sh script when I plug my USB 3.0 external hard disk to my home server.

I created a new file in `/etc/udev/rules.d` called `10-custom.rules`. In this folder I have other files: `70-persistent-cd.rules`, `60-vboxdrv.rules` and `70-persistent-net.rules`.

This is what I wrote in the file (all in one single line):

```
BUS="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}="1058", SYSFS{product}="Western Digital Technologies, Inc.", NAME="gioviusb", RUN+="/home/scripts/usbplug.sh"
```

This is the output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 006 Device 011: ID 1058:0748 Western Digital Technologies, Inc.
```

Every other solution I found seems to be outdated. I am running debian 7 wheezy.

Comment: This looks reasonable. What happens when you try? Have you double-checked the attribute values? Have you tried `udevadm test`?

Comment: I did not know `udevadm test`. This is the result: `run_command: calling: test \
adm_test: version 175 \
syspath parameter missing`.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved.
I issued this command to make `udev` log to syslog: `udevadm control --log-priority=info`
After digging in syslog I noticed this error:

```
Jun 10 10:33:16 GC01SRVR udevd[4707]: failed to execute '/home/scripts/usbplug.sh' '/home/scripts/usbplug.sh': Exec format error
```

Which i solved by putting in the first line of my `/home/scripts/usbplug.sh` script the following text:

```
#!/bin/sh
```